# MySQL dump file installation

Tags: database, backups

I am working on replication, and I am stuck on MySQL dump. I want to know if there is the need of installing MySQL dump (I just have mysql community ed: version 5.5 on both servers)
because I am stuck on executing dump command. On Google I did't find any solution.

Comment: It doesn't seem this question is related to Drupal.

Comment: yes You may be rite. but I am using Drupal application. and I am performing that on Drupal database. so i posted it here.

Comment: If the answer doesn't change when, e.g., it is involved Wordpress, then the question is not about Drupal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqldump should just come bundled with MySQL. Have you tried running it from the command line? If you don't have/can't find mysqldump you should be able to use phpmyadmin to do export/import.

Comment: I tried using command line. but command does not executed. prompt with an error. as unknown command. and I have to use MySQL dump b/c its needed in replication.

Comment: Have you looked for the actual executable file? May not be in you path.